# Synchronize the time of two PCs using pool.ntp.org

Tags: ubuntu, sync, latency, ntp

I am synchronizing the time of two PCs (for some network latency experiment). I know **NTP Pool Time Servers** can also do this job for ubuntu. (Of course, some software like NetTime works on Windows.). There are many NTP servers in each area zone/country zone. For example, if I use Asia-Singapore zone by copying:

```
   server 0.sg.pool.ntp.org
   server 1.sg.pool.ntp.org
   server 2.sg.pool.ntp.org
   server 3.sg.pool.ntp.org
```

There are more than **20 servers in** [**Singapore zone**](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/sg). My PC time will be just synchronized with a random one of these 20+ servers. Hence, my concern is:

**Is this method accurate to synchronize the time of 2 PCs**? Even each sync lag can be less than 10 ms, they may use two different servers in a same country zone. Can I assume those severs in the same zone are all synchronized well (e.g. lags between each others are less than 10 ms)? If yes, can I consider the lag between my two PCs can be less than 20-30 ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ntpdate . Install ntpdate, and put a cron job to use it as simple as `ntpdate -u yourServerToSync`. The cron job can has the frequency you need but once a day is enough I think. After first sync, both pcs are going to sync to the time server at same time everyday.

Comment: Even I use ntpdate -u 0.sg.pool.ntp.org, one random server in sg.pool zone will be used for synchronization. What I concern is whether different severs within same zone has ignoble lags with each other?

Comment: I just tested and found only the nearest server (same IP) will be assigned for sync.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly [ntpdate is depreciated](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate) so you shouldn't use that in a production environment now. You should configure and run the ntp daemon correctly configured instead for a reliable timing setup and removing the chances that you will jump the server time (as ntp will continually adjust the clock as required)

As you have seen the problem with just using the pool is that you may get any server it decides based on the dns query, in your situation you should pick 3 - 5 low stratum servers directly and add those to your config on both machines. ntp likes to have a *minimum* of 3 servers and *ideally* 5 to sync from to ensure a robust time domain.

If you pick some low stratum servers they *should* all be within a few ms of each other (if not better) and provided they are configured correctly you shouldn't need to worry. If your requirements grow and you need to sync more machines then you could run your own server to ensure that what you serve internally only ever comes from 1 reference source at a time.

Comment: I tried somthing ntpdate -u 0.sg.pool.ntp.org (Singapore servers) on both computers, and found the same ip address (of the server) is also shown in the results. I guess only the address with mininum hops will be used for ntp sync?